# Unable to get a valid IPN postback with django-paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, django-paypal

After spending several hours trying to get django-paypal (originally dcramer's fork) to get a 200 OK response from PayPal IPN, I pinpointed the error to PayPal adding an empty, spurious `&cmd=` argument when using the IPN Simulator. If I leave the `&cmd=` in, I get a 400 Bad Request response when I try to postback; if I take it out I get a 200 OK but, of course, the postback is invalid because it's not what PayPal sent my server.

Of course, I'd be absolutely happy to do away with the IPN Simulator entirely and simply use Sandbox accounts, but those are broken too: the ones I create through the developer interface can't login (login failed errors); the ones I created through the "regular" interface on the sandbox site don't send any IPN whatsoever no matter what.

So, actually there's two questions here:

1. is there a way to work around the IPN Simulator `&cmd=` bug?
2. is there a way to make the sandbox accounts work?

A reply to either one would make me very very happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the issues you've experienced are now cleared up. The IPN issue and some developer/sandbox log in issues have been cleared up as of Monday evening. If you are still experiencing any issues please let me know and I'll be more than willing to look into this further.